# Does "merge command" work with link on different sql servers? (S: Potrgesql, T: MsSQL => MERGE)

Tags: sql-server, merge, postgresql-9.1, linked-server

I am doing Slowly Changed Dimension SCD1 and SCD2 operations with my source server Postgresql, my target server MSSQL and SSIS. It takes me a lot of time to select a tool from the toolbard constantly. I want to use the MERGE command instead. I want to use the Merge command by giving a link. Is this possible ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for 3 years now. You should plan an upgrade to a current version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right, the following code worked in the small table. Giving OleDB link to large tables will solve the situation. Sorry, there is currently no free OleDB provider for PostgreSQL.

```
    MERGE INTO [MYTEST_STAGE1].dbo.DimOrganizationType AS t USING
      (SELECT ID,
              CompanyID,
              Name,
              LocationTypeID
       FROM POSTGRESQL35W.erp.[ERP].OrganizationType) AS s (ID, CompanyID, Name, LocationTypeID) ON t.ID=s.ID WHEN MATCHED
    AND (isnull(t.CompanyID, 0)<>isnull(s.CompanyID, 0)
         OR t.Name<>s.Name
         OR isnull(t.LocationTypeID, 0)<>isnull(s.LocationTypeID, 0)) THEN
    UPDATE
    SET t.CompanyID=s.CompanyID,
        t.Name=s.Name,
        t.LocationTypeID=s.LocationTypeID,
        t.ModifiedDate=GETDATE(),
        t.ModifiedByUser=@@SERVERNAME+'/'+@@SERVICENAME WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (ID,
            CompanyID,
            Name,
            LocationTypeID,
            loadDate,
            LoadByUser)
    VALUES (s.ID, s.CompanyID, s.Name, s.LocationTypeID, GETDATE(), @@SERVERNAME+'/'+@@SERVICENAME) WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by create merge statement with USING as subquery with openquery to the PostgreSQL linked server. But the performance should be a problem. I prefer to load the copy of your PostgreSQL table to the MsSQL table and then perform MERGE statement. It depends on the size of your source table, because the table is by request from the PostgreSQL always loaded in the tempdb database.

Comment: Yes you're right, the following code worked in the small table. Giving OleDB link to large tables will solve the situation. Sorry, there is currently no free OleDB provider for PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you install ODBC Driver (which is of course free https://odbc.postgresql.org/ ) and add on your server DSN there is no problem to add linked server with Microsoft OLE DB provider for ODBC Drivers - all for free